# Finding errors in code for ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi I'm using Ionic and I'm trying to build an app, and everything seems to be right when I go through my code but when I go to ionic serve, all I see is a blank screen. Does anybody know how to find an error, at least I mean I have gone through the code multiple times and can't find anything that would be breaking my app. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Anything display in console?

Comment: Nothing displays in the console that suggests why the  build is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `$ ionic serve`, you can use the built-in web inspector from your browser. In most browsers, you can activate this by right-clicking on your webpage and click on **inspect element**.

If you're using Google Chrome for example, this is named the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). If you 'inspect element' and click on the **console** tab, you will see errorlogs if there are any.

Comment: Yea I figured I could do that sort of thing just wasn't sure if there was a better way. Thanks.